# Why are my cells too small when I run my code and visualise my user interface?

Tags: xcode, tableview

I designed my Table View with a customised cell. I set the height of my custom cells to 350 but when I run my code and visualise my user interface, only the image of my cell can be seen and not fully ! I cannot visualise my whole cell, it makes up 1/10 of my table view. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the height of my custom cells to 350

The height of the cell as shown in the storyboard or xib doesn't matter. It is ignored!

What's important is what the *table* thinks the cell height is. You can set this in several ways:

- Set the table view's `rowHeight` to 350. But that sets the height of *all* the cells.
- Or, return 350 from your implementation of `heightForRowAt` for these cells.
- Or, give the table view only an *estimated* row height, but then your cells must have sufficient internal autolayout constraints top to bottom to determine completely and unambiguously the height.